# Site is very slow only the first request

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, httpwebrequest

When browsing "http://dev.bindsolution.com/" the site takes too long to begin processing. Why this?

Are using "CSS Sprites", "css" and "JavaScript" minify although I do not think the problem is this.

Why the first request the site is extremely slow?

PS: I'm visiting from Brazil

Comment: Does the first request involve some database access that subsequent requests don't?

Comment: No, all requests access database!

Answer (score 5):

When you first request the site after publishing, ASP.Net needs to compile and load the application.

Comment: Okay, I know it!
But it is the first request from any user.
The first request of any user, will be slow! Even after the compile and load the IIS application.

Comment: Try to access the link http://dev.bindsolution.com/
You'll find that will be very slow to start charging, but after loading, the next request will be much faster!

Comment: You're using too many external resources from remote servers.  Look at Firebug's Net tab for more details.  Change your design to use fewer files.

Answer (score 0):

IIS may have shut down some worker threads which need to be started, your appDomain will be starting and loading all classes from your dlls and JITing these to machine code, ASP.Net will also be doing it's own warmup (initialising all things required in the pipeline, possibly pre-compiling some views etc).

**Update**

The first request is slow because of the number of resources that the page has to load, once loaded, the browser will cache them do they will not need to be requested again (which is why there's the speed improvement).

Consider aggregating (and possibly compressing) all required resources on your own site, and referencing those in your pages.

Comment: Is the first request by any user!
I know that after  IIS reset the first request will be slow .. but the next, (made by any user) will not be!

Comment: Try to access the link http://dev.bindsolution.com/
You'll find that will be very slow to start charging, but after loading, the next request will be much faster!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you mean by first request.. Is it first request after an application (or app pool) has been redeployed/restarted,  the very first request to your application is slow could be that IIS has to start the asp.net worker process.

also this link should provide you with more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

if you mean first request by any user well then there is an overhead on the files that needs to be downloaded by the user, also the site might be doing some process intensive stuff in Session_start, I would check all these..

Also if you have access to the code you could probably run some performance analysis on the same. I would highly recommend dotTrace by JetBrains.

FYI, I am no way associated with JetBrains. Just love their sw/tools

Comment: Is the first request by any user!
My application does not use the event "session_start"

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the first load is slow and subsequent loads are quicker because assets (js, css, images ) are cached for subsequent views and don't need to be loaded.

The firefox plugin yslow will give you a detailed breakdown on the sizes and loading speeds.

Also run smush.it ( part of yslow ) to shrink your image sizes. It will make the images smaller but there will be no noticeable difference.

Comment: I had seen it:
One question: base64 images, inline css is also performed in a request?

What we do not understand is why these images appear as a request.


**Another question**, is the delay in starting the download. Note that in firebug or Google Chrome Developer after starting the download of resources, the download is done quickly.